# how to run services using broadcast receiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

how to start background services using broadcast receiver. made one services for camera lock operation but after some time function is not working . service is running in android devices. but method of services in onstartcommand not working.

> used action.user_present but its not working .

```
 public class camerareceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{ 
public static String TESTACT_S = "android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"; 
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     if(intent.getAction().equals(TESTACT_S))
      { context.startService(newIntent("com.simsys.camera.ServiceTemplate")); } }
```

Comment: What is problem? Show the relevant code and Logcat.

Comment: used action.user_present but its not working .public class camerareceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{ public static String TESTACT_S = "android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"; @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { if(intent.getAction().equals(TESTACT_S)){ context.startService(new Intent("com.simsys.camera.ServiceTemplate")); } }in log cat no bug displayed . but when run service , camera is working instead of to lock camera.

Comment: See if these can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329810/intent-action-user-present-not-received-on-honeycomb-or-ics-samsung-devices and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750854/bring-task-to-front-on-android-intent-action-user-present

Answer (score 0):

start service from BroadcastReceiver as:

```
public class CamReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
   Toast.makeText(context, "ACTION_USER_PRESENT",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 context.startService(new Intent(context,ServiceTemplate.class));
}
}
}
```

In manifest :

```
<receiver android:name= ".CamReceiver">
           <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
           </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: used action.user_present but its not working .public class camerareceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
 public static String TESTACT_S = "android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             
             
          if(intent.getAction().equals(TESTACT_S)){
                 context.startService(new Intent("com.simsys.camera.ServiceTemplate"));
                 

        }
        }

Comment: see my edit answer or if not get solved then post your catlog stacktrace and code

Comment: com.simsys.camera.ServiceTemplate your package or another app?

Comment: com.simsys.camera is my package name and service template is service name

Comment: @user1345747 : just wait it'will work sure bez we are doing in right way. i have add a toast in broadcast reciver so it's appear or not when you have testing on device?

Comment: when i use alarm manager to wake up camera feature it will not work . it gives fail to open camera service error.